# Ubuntu freezes frequently

Tags: 14.04

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my system which is having the following configuration,

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 339a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I got this details through `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`. My model is HP Compaq Pro 6300.

It becomes heavily unresponsive with Cursor moves very slowly or sometime cursor disappears, the only way to get back the control is, restarting the system. I'm not sure why it is happening. Any help on this would be really great as it is greatly irritating me.

Comment: Have you checked your HDD's health yet? (if its a mechanical drive)

Comment: @jkrix How to check that?

Comment: To rule this out you could download and create bootable media for [Seagate Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/) or install and run software like gsmartcontrol (can be installed through the software center). With Seatools I would recommend you use the long test just to be thorough. Please let me know how you go.

Comment: @Udhay did you find any good solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Anonymous not yet :(